# Linq to DataTable - Cannot find anonymous types

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have this script. I need to populate variable `a` and variable `b` to a DataTable.

**My error is**

> ienumerable anonymous(string a, string b) type does not contain a
>   definition and no extension method

**My script**

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

DataTable dt= new DataTable(); 
Create.Columns.Add("ColumnName");
Create.Columns.Add("DataType");

var lo = from p in jObject["result"]["fields"]
select new {
 a=(string)p["type"],
 b=  (string)p["id"] };
  foreach (var item in lo)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(lo.a);

            }
```

**I tried this also**

```
// get a list of object arrays corresponding    
// to the objects listed in the columns    
// in the datatable above.

var result = from p in jObject["result"]["fields"]    

             select dt.LoadDataRow(    
                new object[] { (string)p["type"], (string)p["id"] },    
                false);        

// the end result will be a set of DataRow objects that have been    
// loaded into the DataTable.
```

How come I cannot find a and b?

Comment: Why are you using `lo.a` and not `item.a`?

Comment: No reason to cast to `string` when you are putting in an `object` array anyway. What is wrong with the `LoadDataRow`?

Comment: @NetMage It doesnt have any errors. It simply just dont fill up the DataTable. So its empty...Okay, thanks!

Comment: Maybe im missing an into?

Comment: You problem is you are trying to use LINQ to execute actions. LINQ doesn't run code by default, the datatype of Result is an `IQueryable` that represents the code  to be run when the query is executed at some later time. `result` represents the query, not a set of data. You should use `foreach`: `foreach (var p in jObject["result"]["fields"]) dt.LoadDataRow(new[] { p["type"], p["id"] }, false);`

Comment: @NetMage Thanks . What if i want to use CopyToDataTAble instead? The problem is that i dont want to loop through each row, since my json can have many rows.

Comment: How do you think `CopyToDataTable` works? You will be looping through each row regardless, there is no way around that.

Comment: @NetMage Thanks I made a hole new solution without linq. Then i could do what i wanted without loops.

Comment: How did you manage that?

Comment: @NetMage I looped through properties of my JObject and when my key name was a specific name, i did a JsonConvert and converted the Json to a DataTable